Identifying resistors
I have these resistors that I feel are not clear in how to read their resistance value. My electronic hardware experience is limited but I have played around with Arduinos and Raspberry Pis a little bit in the past. As well as a long time ago a PLC and related wiring. Today, in an effort to identify the resistor value in these units I was looking at charts online. As well as reading guides about comparing resistors and identifying their values. But I must admit that there are some parts I am unsure about. So I would like your opinion in what resistor values you assess these units as having.

My questions are:

What resistance value do you assess each of these 3 types of units as having?
What are the main ways you personally identified that they have these values and could not have other values?
What does the band thickness indicate?
How do you identify with certainty which direction to read the band side from? I understand there should be some cues from the distance between the bands, most notably in the picture I feel this is clear in the brownish looking resistor. But the two teal/blue resistors I feel as though it is much less clear.
What do you do when you feel like the colour bands are ambigously painted?

I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you for your assistance.

Hello and welcome to EE! As the MMUs (multimeters) are cheap, spend these couple of dollars and buy one. This allows to answer all these questions in one simple measurement. Especially if it comes to 5-band resistors. They should be done as: 4 bands with similar distances between them, bigger distance and tolerance band. But as you see here, it is hard to notice that. The most right resistor is 10kOhm with 5% tolerance. Most left: as there is no orange band to mark tolerance, it must be orange, orange, black, orange (330 kohm) with 1% tolerance.

Thanks for your response.

It looks like you have a 330kohm and 2.7kohm. And the ones that are easiest to read are 10kOhms.

There are two solutions: use a $10 multimeter from Amazon
2: search up a resistor band chart on Google

3: Use the chart (or commit it to memory, one way or another) and check it with the multimeter. You may even find dodgy resistors that don't match the colour codes if you buy from eBay or equivalents.


Values:
330 * 1000 = 330k 1%
270 *   10 = 2k7  1%
10 * 1000 = 10k  5%

Looked at the colour rings.

Ring width or spaces between them may offer cues which way to read it, but not always.

Some resistors values exist and some do not exist. Gold can never be first colour as it only is used for tolerance. Take likelyhoods into account. For example, the 2700k 1% resistor is more likely, as reading it the other ways would make it 110 * 10M 2% resistor.

Measure it.


